# Only Output True or False in Code (loops)

Tags: python

I wanted to do a code that takes in an integer input, then finds if it is divisible by a two-digit prime number. If it is, it returns True, otherwise False. I already have made a function that identifies whether a number is prime or not called isPrime (which I used here):

```
num=int(input())
for i in range (10,num):
    if isPrime(i,2):
        if num%i==0:
            print(True)
        else:
            print(False)
```

I know that this prints all of the True's and False's from 10 to the inputted integer, so what I wanted to ask is how do I edit this so that if one of those outputs is True, it will only output True, but if none of those are True, it will output False?

Comment: Please look up algorithms for finding prime numbers.
The loop technique is found there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break out of the loop when you find the first divisor. Use `else:` to print `False` if the loop finishes without breaking.

```
num=int(input())
for i in range (10,num):
    if isPrime(i,2) and num%i==0:
        print(True)
        break
else:
    print(False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `any`:

```
num=int(input())
print(any(num%i==0 for i in range (10,num) if isPrime(i,2)))
```

`any` returns `True` when it finds the first "Truthy" value in an iterable otherwise `False`

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```py
#function that looks for an element in an array, if found it returns true otherwise false
def includes(array, el):
  for i in range(len(array)):
    if array[i] == el:
      return True
  return False

arr = [] //empty array
num=int(input())
for i in range (10,num):
    if isPrime(i,2):
        if num%i==0:
            arr.push(True)
        else:
            arr.push(False)
print(includes(array, True)) #writes True if there is at least one True value in the array, otherwise it writes False
```

Comment: `array` is a builtin don't overwrite builtins with variable names

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable:

```
num=int(input())
isTrue = False
for i in range(10,num):
    if isPrime(i,2):
        if num%i==0:
            isTrue = True
print(isTrue)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python builtin function `any`

```
Help on built-in function any in module builtins:

any(iterable, /)
    Return True if bool(x) is True for any x in the iterable.
    
    If the iterable is empty, return False.
```

```py
num=int(input())
l = []
for i in range (10,num):
    if isPrime(i,2):
        if num%i==0:
            l.append(True)
            print(any(l))
        else:
            l.append(False)
            print(any(l))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you expected..?

```
def isPrime(number, digit):
    return True if number % digit else False

for i in range (10):
    num = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    if isPrime(num,2): # print(f'{num} is not divisible by {2}')
        print('True')
        break
```